How do I set the frame number font size in Beamer to a smaller font size
I have tried using the \setbeamertemplate for the footline with no success. I have also tried \setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\tiny}.  Nothing seems to change the frame number size.  Any help would be appreciated.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

For the themes which come as part as beamer, you can change the size of the framenumber via the page number in head/foot font.
3rd-party themes might use a different font.
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\Tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thanks.  I used the code you provided and it worked just fine.  I copied the line \setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\Tiny} into my original file and it did not work.  I started copying line by line my old file with the setup code you provided and finally found the culprit.  There was a statement "\pagestyle{plain}" that had somehow been loaded as part of a template I was using for another \documentclass{article} .  I am really not sure where that came from but when I deleted that line item everything works just fine.  Thanks again!!

@Gary You're welcome!
